# Customize exit operation when closing tab or browser

Tags: javascript, html, primefaces

Hi i'm trying to customize the operation made when a tab/browser is closed on my software.
I've found a script that stop the execution of the closing operation and display a popup that ask to confirm the exit intent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue='';
    });
</script>
```

I want to make this script execute other operation like showing a confirm dialog, but cant figure out how to make it. I want something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
        e.stopClosing();
        //Show confirm dialog
    });
</script>
```

I'm using Primefaces and JSF. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible in JavaScript because that would be a big security problem. Every browser has its own `beforeunload` dialog style and you can't customize it.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) says:

> The default message that appears in the confirmation box, is different in different browsers. However, the standard message is something like "Are you sure you want to leave this page?". **This message cannot be removed.**